# Unable to send api response data from express to react after refreshing the page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

I'm learning react and node js with express framework and I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve API data from express to react.

I retrieved data from backend express js where I made a simple json value. My backend server.js code is given below.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = 3001;


app .get('/api/contents',(req,res)=>{
    const contents=[
        {
            "id":0,
            "heading":"Joshua Tree Overnight Adventure",
            "content":"A sight in the blue sea..."
        },
        {
            "id":1,
            "heading":"Catch waves with an adventure guide",
            "content":"Lorem.."
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "heading":"Catch waves with an adventure guide",
            "content":"Lorem epsum ..."
        }
    ];
    res.json(contents)
})
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("express server is running...")
})
```

In react app, I used axios to retrieve those values from backend and tried to pass the api values of content with id= 0 as props in "TheLatestArticles" component. I have updated proxy in package.json in react to connect  backend. The below code is the mainhomepage component where it is enclosed with TheLatestArticles component with props value

**MainHomePage.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function MainHomePage(){

    const [content,setContent]=useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchPosts = async ()=>{
            const res =await axios.get("/api/contents")
            setContent(res.data)
            console.log(res)
        }
        fetchPosts()
    },[])
    return (
        <>
        <TheLatestArticle content={content} />
        </>
       );
}

export default MainHomePage;
```

**TheLatestArticle.js**

```
import cardImage from "./../../Images/card.jpg"
import './TheLatestArticleCard.css';
const TheLatestArticleCard=(props)=>{
    console.log(props)
    return(
        <>
        <div className="card">
            <div className="image">
                <img src={cardImage} alt="cardimg"/>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                <p className="heading">{props.content.heading}</p>
                <p className="body-content">{props.content.content}</p>
            
            <div className="details">
                <p className="details-info">Travel <span className="details-info-2">/ August 21 2017</span></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default TheLatestArticleCard;
```

When I run the application, It displayed all the api values in the screen given below.
[image]

I console.log the api values inside useEffect and it displayed all the api values perfectly.

[image]

But when I refresh the page, the api value became undefined and gave me this error[image]

Can you please solve me this issue with the reason behind this error? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
{(content && content.length > 0) && <TheLatestArticle content={content} />}
```

Since your API call is async there won't be any data in content initially. After a while, your API is called and data is fetched. Then you will have data. To prevent `TheLatestArticle` to blow up we add some conditions when to show that component. The error in the screenshot is when you try to use a property `heading` from `content` where content is empty.

Now with the condition, `TheLatestArticle` will not render until there is some data.

**Update**

You are using `<TheLatestArticle content={content} />` and content is assumed to be an object. But as per your code, it's an array. If you are not already using `content.map((c)=> <TheLatestArticle content={c} />)` you should do that.